# Performance of "INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE" compared to "UPDATE"

Tags: mysql

99% of the time a single `UPDATE` will suffice, but less than 0.01% of the time I need to follow up with an `INSERT` on the same key.  This can be written as a single `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` but, in terms of performance, should I?

The question is basically if `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`s are expected to be slower than `UPDATE`s in MySQL.

Some code to demonstrate:

**Code using `UPDATE`**

```
UPDATE foo SET seq = @new_seq WHERE id = X AND seq = @prev_seq;

IF rows_changed = 0 THEN
    INSERT INTO foo (id, seq) VALUES (X, @new_seq)
    IF <duplicate key error> THEN
        -- handle collusion
    END IF
END IF
```

**Code using `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`**

```
INSERT INTO foo (id, seq) VALUES (X, @new_seq)
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE seq = IF(seq = @prev_seq, VALUES(seq), seq)

IF rows_changed = 0 THEN
    -- handle collusion
END IF
```

Comment: You can benchmark them, but the first one should be more efficient. And more so in your case because you only need the `INSERT` in 0.01% of the cases. However, a better way than both is to know when to use `UPDATE` and when to use `INSERT` and never use any of them at the wrong time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

#### It is strongly recommended that you benchmark them by yourself.

It's quite easy to do, and it's more persuasive.

---

**In theory**, I don't think that the `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will drag you down.

#### CASE 1: update table without index

In this case, the `UPDATE` operation will lock all records in this table. But `INSERT` operation only locks a gap(Insert Intention Lock) and the inserted record.

Since you used `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` here, it's more likely that you are updating table with index.

#### CASE 2: update table with index

Let's assume that you are updating table with a primary key. Both `UPDATE` and `INSERT` will pay the same cost to find the specific record in a B+ tree. And it's the same for `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`. So there is no reason `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` would be much slower.

What's more, `INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` won't add a Insert Intention Lock if a duplicate key is found. It will only add a `IX` lock on the table and a `X` lock on the specific record, just as the `UPDATE` do.

Comment: Case 2 sounds reasonable and gave me the confidence to go ahead with it.  I benchmarked nevertheless and it was roughly 3 seconds either way for 10,000 updates batched so no noticeable difference.  Case 1 seems to be comparing semantically different things.

Comment: Exactly, I just want to list all the situations, and Case 2 is what you're facing here.